# `get_variable()` doesn't recognize existing variables for tf.estimator

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-estimator

This question has been asked [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/1325), difference is my problem is focused on `Estimator`.

Some context: We have trained a model using estimator and get some variable defined within Estimator `input_fn`, this function preprocesses data to batches. Now, we are moving to prediction. During the prediction, we use the same `input_fn` to read in and process the data. **But got error saying variable (word_embeddings) does not exist** (variables exist in the chkp graph), here's the relevant bit of code in `input_fn`:

```
with tf.variable_scope('vocabulary', reuse=tf.AUTO_REUSE):
    if mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.TRAIN:
        word_to_index, word_to_vec = load_embedding(graph_params["word_to_vec"])
        word_embeddings = tf.get_variable(initializer=tf.constant(word_to_vec, dtype=tf.float32),
                                          trainable=False,
                                          name="word_to_vec",
                                          dtype=tf.float32)
    else:
        word_embeddings = tf.get_variable("word_to_vec", dtype=tf.float32)
```

basically, when it's in prediction mode, `else` is invoked to load up variables in checkpoint. Failure of recognizing this variable indicates a) inappropriate usage of scope; b) graph is not restored. I don't think scope matters that much here as long as `reuse` is set properly.

I suspect that is because the graph is not yet restored at `input_fn` phase. Usually, the graph is restored by calling `saver.restore(sess, "/tmp/model.ckpt")` [reference](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/saved_model). Investigation of estimator [source code](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.12/tensorflow/python/estimator/estimator.py#L508) doesn't get me anything relating to restore, the best shot is MonitoredSession, a wrapper of training. It's already been stretch so much from the original problem, not confident if I'm on the right path, I'm looking for help here if anyone has any insights.

One line summary of my question: How does graph get restored within `tf.estimator`, via `input_fn` or `model_fn`?

Comment: There definitely seems to be a difference between how a session is normally run vs using an Estimator that is afaik not in any of the Estimator documentation.

Comment: Graph will be restored by setting `scaffold=estimator_spec.scaffold` within `MonitorSession`. The `MonitorSession` is called by estimator.predict.

Answer (score 1):

Hi I think that you error comes simply because you didn't specify the shape in the tf.get_variable (at predict) , it seems that you need to specify the shape even if the variable is going to be restored.

I've made the following test with a simple linear regressor estimator that simply needs to predict x + 5

```
def input_fn(mode):
    def _input_fn():
        with tf.variable_scope('all_input_fn', reuse=tf.AUTO_REUSE):
            if mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.TRAIN:
                var_to_follow = tf.get_variable('var_to_follow', initializer=tf.constant(20))
                x_data = np.random.randn(1000)
                labels = x_data + 5
                return {'x':x_data}, labels
            elif mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.PREDICT:
                var_to_follow = tf.get_variable("var_to_follow", dtype=tf.int32, shape=[])
                return {'x':[0,10,100,var_to_follow]}
    return _input_fn

featcols = [tf.feature_column.numeric_column('x')]
model = tf.estimator.LinearRegressor(featcols, './outdir')
```

This code works perfectly fine, the value of the const is 20 and also for fun use it in my test set to confirm :p

However if you remove the shape=[] , it breaks, you can also give another initializer such as tf.constant(500) and everything will work and 20 will be used.

By running

```
model.train(input_fn(tf.estimator.ModeKeys.TRAIN), max_steps=10000)
```

and

```
preds = model.predict(input_fn(tf.estimator.ModeKeys.PREDICT))
print(next(preds))
```

You can visualize the graph and you'll see that  a) the scoping is normal and b) the graph is restored.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thanks! Within a `tf.graph` you do not necessarily to specify the shape, tested it locally, if needed I can upload the code as well. Weird thing is you have to do that in Estimator.

Comment: I guess that in the case of estimators the graph is created each time when you call train, evaluate or predict, then the weights are restored. It can explain this behavior. As you can see in https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.12/tensorflow/python/estimator/estimator.py#L574 , you first call input_fn , then model_fn (build the graph) and finally you'll restore the weights through the Monitored Session.

Comment: [This](https://medium.com/@tijmenlv/an-advanced-example-of-tensorflow-estimators-part-3-3-8c2efe8ff6fa) article could help. It explains where sessions are called for both `input_fn` and `model_fn`.